# Sqlite query to retrieve count of items

Tags: sql, sqlite, count

I have two columns in my sqlite table, items and date. Each date may have many items. Now i want to fetch no. of item counts on each date between give date range. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date,
       COUNT(*) AS count
FROM MyTable
WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ?
GROUP BY date;
```

Comment: How to include the results with zero values?

Comment: Show some example data and the desired result.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1caZhs6huLXyBxQIvDWUSsHdNn7QOr0Hho5N3AoTcpfE/edit?usp=sharing here it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
SELECT Date,count(*) from Table WHERE date between ... AND ... GROUP BY Date
```